# Cannot get data from related models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models in different namespace.

```
class Admin::Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authorization_roles
end


class AuthorizationRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :membership
end
```

The Membership model is in different folder with AuthorizationRole model (I don't know what is called)

When run `Admin::Membership.find(:all)`, the data from AuthorizationRole model is not included. I've create membership_id field on authorization_roles table, but I still can't get both models related. Is something wrong in this code? Sorry if I'm missing something basic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used namespaced models and I don't think you need to... but maybe you'll have to specify the class name in AuthorizationRole, something like:

```
belongs_to :membership, :class_name => 'Admin::Membership'
```

UPDATE:

Assuming you have:

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authorization_roles
end

class AuthorizationRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :membership
end
```

You have added an integer column called membership_id to authorization_roles and you've run the migrations. Now you should be able to create authorization_roles like this `@membership.authorization_roles.create( ... )` and fetch them `@membership.authorization_roles`

Comment: No changes, I'm already try that, or maybe I have to specify what field to make relation?

Comment: I've try to move the file to the same folder and don't use the namespace, but I got no changes.

Comment: Huh, it's strange, it's work after I remigrate the models... Thanks @jordinl

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
class Admin::Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authorization_roles, :class_name => '::AuthorizationRole'
end


class AuthorizationRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :membership, :class_name => 'Admin::Membership'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you are setting the table name prefix. The Rails model generator adds a file like this for namespaced models:

```
# /app/models/admin.rb
module Admin
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'admin_'
  end
end
```

Note: this is Rails version 3.0.1 -- not sure about earlier versions.